# Xcode 8.2 simulator crash and quits on saving a screenshot while debugging

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

I updated my Xcode to 8.2 and since then if I try to take a screenshot while debugging it is crashing and then quits.

I tried iOS 9.0 and 10.0 simulators and it happen with both of them.'

Thanks

> **Update:**
>
> **8.2.1 - Doesn't works**
>
> **8.3 - Works only with Mac OS Sierra**

Comment: Check out - http://www.jeenalinfotech.com/blogs/ios/xcode-8-2-simulator-crash-when-save-screen-shot/

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Please try this approach for taking screenshot

> You can take videos and screenshots of Simulator using the `xcrun` Xcode command-line utility. To take a screenshot, run the command `xcrun simctl io booted screenshot`. To take a video, run the command `xcrun simctl io booted recordVideo <filename>.<file extension>`. (9887264)

source :[Xcode 8.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051)

> Simulator can crash when saving a screenshot when running on OS X El Capitan. (29182710) The crash does not occur on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Just in case, with path to desktop (like "Save Screen Shot" original behavior) ->

xcrun simctl io booted screenshot ~/Desktop/filename.png

Answer (score 17):

There is a nice simple way around it.

1. In the simulators menu go *edit->copy screen*.
2. Then open "Preview" and press *cmd+n (New from Clipboard)*.
3. Export - give it a name and enjoy your lovely screenshot.

Comment: This is actually great as I more often want the image on the clip board than in a file.

Comment: Thank you, saved my life. Really. Some Apple bugs are inconceivable!

Comment: @Ivan, what do you mean by open "Preview" I can't see any option in the tabl bar to open Preview. Thanks

Comment: @bibscy Preview is an application installed on your mac ;) Hope that helps! :D

Comment: This is simple and wonderful! Actually sometimes it seems to be the only way around the crash sometimes. Particularly when you want to grab a huge iPad pro screenshot for the store...

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, unfortunately, this is tripping over a bug in Foundation on OS X 10.11.  You won't have the problem if you upgrade to macOS Sierra.

If you cannot upgrade to Sierra right now, you can still take screenshots from the commandline:

```
xcrun simctl io booted screenshot <path to output file>
```

This is mentioned in the [Xcode 8.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051)

> Simulator can crash when saving a screenshot when running on OS X El Capitan. (29182710)
>   The crash does not occur on macOS Sierra.

Answer (score 0):

For a static screenshot, an easier and faster workaround is to type COMMAND+SHIFT+4, then hit the space bar until the simulator window is selected, then click on the simulator window to save the screenshot.