# Xcode 8.2 simulator crash when save screen shot

Tags: ios, xcode

After update XCode 8.2, every time save simulator screen shot always made it crash. Even I reset content and settings still crash.

Should I remove all simulator and install them again?

**Update**:

- 8.2.1 has same problem.
- 8.3 only Sierra supported.

---

The following is the crash report:

```
Process:               Simulator [48928]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator
Identifier:            com.apple.iphonesimulator
Version:               10.0 (726.7)
Build Info:            Indigo-726007000000000~5
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Simulator [48928]
User ID:               501

PlugIn Path:             /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftFoundation.dylib
PlugIn Identifier:       libswiftFoundation.dylib
PlugIn Version:          3.0.2 (800.0.63)

Date/Time:             2016-12-13 23:43:25.860 +0800
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1108)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        6E8AEBAE-0AF8-D350-66D6-57EC500D69F5

Sleep/Wake UUID:       6E017B49-1A38-4D3A-AB8F-FD9E200B6286

Time Awake Since Boot: 110000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       10000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       EXC_I386_GPFLT
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Performing @selector(saveScreenShot:) from sender NSMenuItem 0x7fd05a7329f0

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff946adcdc lookUpImpOrForward + 135
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00007fff946a8591 objc_msgSend + 209
2   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00007fff9b684986 _Block_object_assign + 364
3   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8dc21ca4 __copy_helper_block_ + 49
4   libsystem_blocks.dylib          0x00007fff9b68459d _Block_copy_internal + 325
5   libswiftFoundation.dylib        0x000000010178af95 _TToFC10Foundation12_SwiftNSData19enumerateByteRangesfT5usingFTSVVSC8_NSRangeGSpV10ObjectiveC8ObjCBool__T__T_ + 21
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff8db02a94 _NSWriteDataToFileWithExtendedAttributes + 742
7   com.apple.iphonesimulator       0x0000000100ffdc1e 0x100ff1000 + 52254
8   com.apple.iphonesimulator       0x0000000100ffdda9 0x100ff1000 + 52649
9   libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff9a5bd07a _os_activity_initiate + 75
10  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff909d4dbd -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 460
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff909d4b57 -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 336
12  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff909d48b7 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 114
13  libsystem_trace.dylib           0x00007fff9a5bd07a _os_activity_initiate + 75
14  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff909d37a5 -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] + 357
15  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff909d2949 -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] + 920
16  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff908f90fe -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4274
17  com.apple.iphonesimulator       0x000000010100d151 0x100ff1000 + 115025
18  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9075fdf2 -[NSApplication run] + 796
19  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff90729368 NSApplicationMain + 1176
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff99c955ad start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff97827efa kevent_qos + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9612d165 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 216
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fff9612cdcd _dispatch_mgr_thread + 52

Thread 2:: com.apple.NSEventThread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff97820f72 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff978203b3 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97319124 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff973185ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff97317e38 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff908c1d95 _NSEventThread + 149
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a299d _pthread_body + 131
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a291a _pthread_start + 168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a0351 thread_start + 13

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff978275e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a2578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a0341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff978275e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a2578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a0341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff978275e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a2578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a0341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff978275e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a2578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a0341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff978275e2 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a2578 _pthread_wqthread + 1283
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff928a0341 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x00007fff6382b2c0  rbx: 0x00007fff6384ce48  rcx: 0x021b77058d48fb89  rdx: 0x00007fff638545f8
  rdi: 0x00007fff6384ce48  rsi: 0x00007fff976efa45  rbp: 0x00007fff5ec0dc30  rsp: 0x00007fff5ec0dbe0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000001  r10: 0x00007fff93c7d1e0  r11: 0x00007fff6384ce48
  r12: 0x00007fff976efa45  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000001  r15: 0x00007ffffffffff8
  rip: 0x00007fff946adcdc  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x00007fff93c7c000
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulator crashes and quits on saving a screenshot while debugging on Xcode 8.2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125344/simulator-crashes-and-quits-on-saving-a-screenshot-while-debugging-on-xcode-8-2)

Comment: @Cœur To be fair, the question you're referencing was published **one minute** prior to this question, so I'd hardly call it a duplicate.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

The crash seems to occur due to a segmentation fault, or more specifically a general protection fault, while calling the `saveScreenShot:` selector. Why it happens can depend on several things, so it's hard to say whether a reinstall would help.

In any case, if the screenshot (⌘S) function in simulator causes the crash, there's hardly anything you can do about it. The best option you have is probably to file [a bug report to Apple](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/).

***Update:***

I just updated to the 8.2 GM, and low and behold, ⌘S crashes for me as well. Although I'm getting `KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS` instead of `EXC_I386_GPFLT`.

One workaround, for the time being, is copying the screen and pasting into Preview:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 29):

Yeah, unfortunately, this is tripping over a bug in Foundation on OS X 10.11.  You won't have the problem if you upgrade to macOS Sierra.

If you cannot upgrade to Sierra right now, you can still take screenshots from the commandline:

```
xcrun simctl io booted screenshot <path to output file>
```

This is mentioned in the [Xcode 8.2 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051)

> Simulator can crash when saving a screenshot when running on OS X El Capitan. (29182710)
>   The crash does not occur on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Got it. I am stay with the version 10.11.6 as you mention

Comment: What a nice release note, whatever Apple says nobody will complain.

Comment: Yes, sorry about that.  The issue was not noticed until after it was too late to include a workaround.  We added a release note to raise awareness of the issue and inform users of workarounds.

Comment: Just in case, with path to desktop (like "Save Screen Shot" original behavior) ->

xcrun simctl io booted screenshot ~/Desktop/filename.png

Answer (score 20):

Please find the below steps for getting the screenshot.

1) Go to Simulators -> Edit -> Copy Screen or you can use the shortcut (**ctrl + cmd + c**).
2) Open the **Preview** and go to File -> New from Clipboard or you can use the shortcut (**cmd + n**).
3) Now go to File -> Save or you can use the shortcut (**cmd + s**).

Or you can also refer the below GIF presentation.

[image: GIF]

Answer (score 4):

So an easier workaround is this:

1. Run app in simulator (obviously)
2. In simulator go to Edit>Copy Screen
3. Open Preview app
4. Go back to simulator and save screenshot i.e. File>Save Screenshot

Done!

Not sure why this prevents the bug from occurring but it worked for me. It's faster than all the other methods described above.

Answer (score 4):

**Solution 1**

1) Go to Simulators > Edit > Copy Screen (⌃⌘C)

[image]

2) Open Preview App > Go to File > New from Clipboard (⌘N) and Save (⌘S) to your favorite location on your machine

[image]

**Solution 2:-  Using the xcrun Xcode command-line utility**

Open `Terminal App` and run the following command to take screenshot

`xcrun simctl io booted screenshot`

If you wish to save the captured screenshot to specific location

`xcrun simctl io booted screenshot <path_to_output_file>`

Answer (score 2):

Another convenient way -> Shift+Command+4 - tap the space bar, tap on the window to get snapshot of the Simulator's window.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361