# iPhone simulator crashed when I tried to take screenshot (⌘ + S) (using the libswiftFoundation.dylib plug-in)

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, dylib, xcode8.2

I am trying to take screenshot from iPhone 5 simulator. When I click `⌘ + S`, the simulator crashes every time with error:-

> Simulator quit unexpectedly while using the libswiftFoundation.dylib
>   plug-in

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 8.2 simulator crash when save screen shot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125363/xcode-8-2-simulator-crash-when-save-screen-shot)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41125344/xcode-8-2-simulator-crash-and-quits-on-saving-a-screenshot-while-debugging?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2):

If you run the screenshot command from terminal with the following it should save correctly. This seems to be a bug with Xcode versions 8.2.0 and 8.2.1.

```
xcrun simctl io booted screenshot
```

This will save to directly that Terminal is in. You can also add a path to the end of the command